# Unexpected Input in every exponent of my code

Tags: r, hazard

I received these error when i try these code

```r
> fk <- function(u.vect, lambda, alpha, beta, x, k) {
+   res <- sapply(u.vect, function(u) {
+     # Cause-specific hazard
+     hk <-
+       lambda[k] * alpha[k] * (uˆ(alpha[k] - 1)) * exp(sum(unlist(beta[, k]) * x))
Error: unexpected input in:
"    hk <-
      lambda[k] * alpha[k] * (uˆ"
>     # Cumulative cause-specific hazard
>     Hk <-
+       lambda * (rep(u, length(lambda))ˆalpha) * exp((t(beta) %*% matrix(x, ncol = 1))[, 1])
Error: unexpected input in:
"    Hk <-
      lambda * (rep(u, length(lambda))ˆ"
>     # Cause-specific hazard x Overall survival
>     aux <- hk * exp(-sum(Hk))
Error: object 'hk' not found
>     return(aux)
Error: object 'aux' not found
>   })
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   return(res)
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

What does the error mean, and how can I fix it?

Please help, Thank You

Comment: Your `ˆ` looks strange. Mine looks like this: `^`. I think this causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

R is often and unfortunately intolerant of non-ASCII characters, especially as operators. I've replaced the `ˆ` with `^` (as MartinGal suggested) and the function reads/parses without complaint.

```r
fk <- function(u.vect, lambda, alpha, beta, x, k) {
  res <- sapply(u.vect, function(u) {
    # Cause-specific hazard
    hk <-
      lambda[k] * alpha[k] * (u^(alpha[k] - 1)) * exp(sum(unlist(beta[, k]) * x))
    # Cumulative cause-specific hazard
    Hk <-
      lambda * (rep(u, length(lambda))^alpha) * exp((t(beta) %*% matrix(x, ncol = 1))[, 1])
    # Cause-specific hazard x Overall survival
    aux <- hk * exp(-sum(Hk))
    return(aux)
  })
  return(res)
}
```